# Retrieve series name and data with getjson

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to retrieve from a JSON formatted file this series name and data

```
[
    { "name":"gfs00", "data": [ [1359676800000, 30], [1359687600000, 32]] 
    }, 
    { "name":"gfs06", "data": [ [1359676800000, 28], [1359687600000, 29]] 
    }
]
```

Here's the highchart code:

```
var data_temp;

$.getJSON('dati/performance_gfs/precipitazioni/pioggia_live_data.php',  
             { run: runs_gfs} ,function(data_temp){
  for (var i = 0; i <data_temp.length ;i++){
    chart.addSeries({
        data:data_temp,
    });
  }  
});
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container_temperatura_windchill_heatindex',
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      
      zoomType: 'x',      
    },
            
    title: {
      text: 'Ensemble'
    },
            
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
            
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
      id:0, 
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value +'°C';
        },
        style: {
          color: '#89A54E'
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature',
        style: {
          color: '#89A54E'
        }
      }
    }],
     
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        states: {
          hover: {
            lineWidth: 2
          }
        },
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
          states: {
            hover: {
              enabled: true,
              symbol: 'circle',
              radius: 5,
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          }
        },
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600000, // one hour
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0)
      }
    },
            
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', this.x)+'<br/>'+
        this.y;
      }
    },
            
    series: []              
  });
}); 
    
}
```

As can be seen I don't know how to assign the series names and data from the JSON file which is correct what I need is something like http://jsfiddle.net/vXdxv/1/

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I've edited your post to improve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i <data_temp.length ;i++){
    chart.addSeries(data_temp[i], false);
});
chart.redraw();
```